# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to use py2cytoscape from python2.

```
from py2cytoscape import cyrest
cytoscape=cyrest.cyclient()
cytoscape.status()
```

On which I am getting :
Could not get status from CyREST:

HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

What could be the problem?

Comment: There are several potential reasons.  Start with ensure thing there is an http server on `localhost:1234`.  Quickest way to check that is `curl -v http://localhost:1234`.  I don't know how CyREST is set up, but that looks like it may not be running where it is expected to be running.